# overload resolution failed

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use the following LINQ statement to query a database but I keep getting an error saying

> overload resolution failed because no accessible Where can be called
>   with these argument.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please as I've been pulling my hair out over this one all day.

```
Return context.Logins _
.Include("Account.Children") _
.Include("aspnet_Membership") _
.Include("AccountType") _
.AsQueryable() _
.Where(Function(l) Not l.aspnet_Membership.Deleted AndAlso(l.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.LastName.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.aspnet_Membership.Email.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse (1.FirstName & " " & 1.LastName).Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.Account.Children.Any(Function(c) (c.FirstName & " " & c.LastName).Contains(searchTerm)))) _
                            .OrderBy(sortField) _
                            .ToList()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo/relevant but you have 1.FirstName rather than l.firstname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested fix (with '1's changed to 'l's):

```
Return context.Logins _
.Include("Account.Children") _
.Include("aspnet_Membership") _
.Include("AccountType") _
.AsQueryable() _
.Where(Function(l) Not l.aspnet_Membership.Deleted AndAlso(l.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.LastName.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.aspnet_Membership.Email.Contains(searchTerm) OrElse (l.FirstName & " " & l.LastName).Contains(searchTerm) OrElse l.Account.Children.Any(Function(c) (c.FirstName & " " & c.LastName).Contains(searchTerm)))) _
.OrderBy(sortField) _
.ToList()
```